# "bash: ... No such file or directory" returned for all files and directories!

Tags: command-line, bash

I know there are similar questions but mine appears to be a different problem, as I get this error message for all files and directories that I try. I have been trying to install a very particular package in R and have thus been executing commands which I don't fully understand. Now, when I type a simple command such as

```
cd /Desktop
```

it returns

```
bash: cd: /Desktop: No such file or directory
```

Again, it returns this for all files. What have I done?

Comment: You can use `cd ~/Desktop` to access your Desktop

Comment: You could do that if there was a file called '/Desktop'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `cd Desktop` and not `cd /Desktop`.